# google_play_services_version not found

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm trying to use google analytics, I'm sure i did what I was suppose to.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dose.apps.brainnoodles" >



    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/official_launcher_icon1"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"


>


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

here the redness of the messagehttp://i.imgur.com/dP76cxr.png

Comment: The integer that shows up as missing should be bundled with the Google Play Services library. Any chance you imported the library as a jar? If so, you really need to reference the library as a Library Project ([as described here](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)), otherwise all resources will be missing (which may explain your error). Alternatively, you may just need to clean/rebuild your project.

Comment: @MH I did that and now I get this error instead. http://i.imgur.com/qqSUy7A.png

Answer (score 1):

Go to Android SDK Manager (on "Window" option in eclipse), and make sure the google_play_services are installed:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" .../>` element is optional. You can remove it from your ApplicationManifest.xml and Analytics will function correctly. You still need to add Google Play services to your app project.

Answer (score 0):

Please do Build--> Make Project  in your Android Studio first, then Run your App.