# google_play_services_version) not found. error: failed process

Tags: android

After updating to 28 API, I receive this error message:

```
Output:  D:\Mahmoud\0MyApp\Mallion_Hasanah\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:43: error: resource integer/google_play_services_version (aka thepurplecastle.million_hasanah:integer/google_play_services_version) not found.
error: failed processing manifest.
```

Can anyone provide some insight?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020856/google-play-services-version-not-found

Comment: @Mahmoud Ayyad Make sure google play service dependency is added in gradle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google\_play\_services\_version not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020856/google-play-services-version-not-found)

Answer (score -1):

For me I had to remove this line from the app's Gradle file:

```
configurations.all {
    exclude module: 'play-services-basement'
}
```